# Search in ruby hash array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to find in my rails app some data, first i search in rails model all data, and then via some field (which is getting from excel file) i need to find in in my array, but find as sql like %%, so not concrete, but like % % in sql. How to do this in ruby?

```
@suppliers = Supplier.find(:all)
supplier = @suppliers.find{|item| item['SUP_BRAND']=="*"+row[13]+"*"}
```

I do something like that, but that bad idea, is it any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick you want. We're matching against `Regexp` which is constructed from `.*` at the beginning and at the end which is the same as `%` in SQL and putting `row[13]` value between them:

```
@suppliers = Supplier.find(:all)
supplier = @suppliers.find{|item| item['SUP_BRAND'] =~ Regexp.new(".*#{row[13]}.*") }
```

**Updated**

I just checked and "regexp" syntax or how do you call it, will also work in this case:

```
item['SUP_BRAND'] =~ /.*#{row[13]}.*/
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is a partial match, right? Perhaps using regular expressions is the right way to go? Try this:

```
... item['SUP_BRAND'] =~ /row[13]/ ...
```

That will look for the text contained in `row[13]` within the string `item['SUP_BRAND']`. Try using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to play around with regular expressions.

Comment: doesn't work, i need something this: item['SUP_BRAND'] like % row %

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using ActiveRecord. You should just use the built-in querying:

```
Supplier.where("SUP_BRAND like ?", "%#{row[13]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method is an alias for the `detect` method and only returns the first item. I assume you want to return a collection of matching items?

```
@suppliers = Supplier.find(:all)
supplier = @suppliers.select { |item| item['SUP_BRAND'].include?(row[13]) }
```

or with a regex

```
supplier = @suppliers.select { |item| item['SUP_BRAND'] =~ /#{row[13]}/ }
```

But this very inefficient. What if you have hundreds or thousands of suppliers? Curious why this can't be written with straight-up ActiveRecord.

Comment: ok, than how to fetch id from supplier (getted via activerecord), if i write supllier.SUP_ID it gives me undefined method `SUP_ID'

Comment: Is it better to search in hash values? supplier have about 500 rows, ad every %like% is not fast as you think to

Comment: You've got something unconventional (in the Rails world) going on with SUP_BRAND and SUP_ID and this isn't the place to go into design philosophies. If you had a Supplier category (attribute or association) you could avoid the whole LIKE thing, perhaps.

Comment: I feel your pain, man. Sometimes it's like trying to hammer a square peg into a round hole. Still, though, the more you can offload to SQL queries and return only the data you need, the better. Good luck, sir!